# AV when using std::stringstream in dll

Tags: c++, dll, c++builder, access-violation, stringstream

I'm facing a problem, when I use a std::stringstream and call the << operator within a dll. After calling this operator my application reports an access violation when it gets closed.

In my test project there is a exe and and a dll. For both the option "link with dynamic RTL" is active. From the exe the following function of the dll is called:

```
void __stdcall Test(void)
{
    ss.str();
    ss << 1;
}
```

I found a report according to this in QC:
[qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=37491](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=37491)

Has anybody newer informations about this issue or a workaround?
Disabling dynamic linking of the RTL is unfortunately not an option for me.

I can reproduce this with behaviour with C++ Builder XE6 and XE7

Regards
KD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround for this problem by Embarcadero:

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39758#RADStudio2010ReleaseNotes-VCL%2FRTLNotes